# Change color theme to HTML markdown

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, background-color

I'm trying to change the HTML markdown background but I couldn't. For instance, the 'cerulean' theme has a white background, and it's very annoying because my eyes get tired very soon.

I know there are many themes in prettydoc, tint and more but I would like to know how to change the background color, the font style and the font color of my theme using CSS.

Comment: Can you provide us with more information please? It's hard to help you if we don't know what your problem is exactly. Give us some code, examples, ... For more information on how to ask a clear question, visit this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The html r-markdown report has a white background that get my eyes tired very soon. I need to change it to , for example, grey color. I know that I can do it with  a .css file but I don´t know how to call  the "background color of the report" or the "report color". Do yo know how?

Answer (score 0):

```
**Themes for R Markdown**
*With the powerful rmarkdown package, we could easily create nice HTML document by adding some meta information in the header, for example*
-------------
title: Nineteen Years Later
author: S M Sharif Mia
date: feb 03, 2019
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    theme: lumen
----------------
*The html_document engine uses the Bootswatch theme library to support different styles of the document. This is a quick and easy way to tune the appearance of your document, yet with the price of a large file size (> 700KB) since the whole Bootstrap library needs to be packed in.
For package vignettes, we can use the html_vignette engine to generate a more lightweight HTML file that is meant to minimize the package size, but the output HTML is less stylish than the html_document ones.*

**The prettydoc Engine**
*The prettydoc package provides an alternative engine, html_pretty, to knit your R Markdown document into pretty HTML pages. Its usage is extremely easy: simply replace the rmarkdown::html_document or rmarkdown::html_vignette output engine by prettydoc::html_pretty in your R Markdown header, and use one of the built-in themes and syntax highlighters. For example*
---
title: Nineteen Years Later
author: S M Sharif Mia
date: feb 03, 2019
output:
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: cayman
    highlight: github
---
**Options and Themes**
*The options for the html_pretty engine are mostly compatible with the default html_document (see the documentation) with a few exceptions:*

 1. Currently the theme option can take the following values. More themes will be added in the future. 
  = cayman: Modified from the Cayman theme.
  = tactile: Modified from the Tactile theme.
  = architect: Modified from the Architect theme.
  = leonids: Modified from the Leonids theme.
  = hpstr: Modified from the HPSTR theme.
 2. The highlight option takes value from github and vignette.
 3. Options code_folding, code_download and toc_float are not applicable.
```